# Schedule Jenkins job based on parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to set the next build time of a job based on a parameter?

For example, an approval workflow passes a parameter to Jenkins telling it when next to run a job.

Comment: When, where, and how do you expect to enter this parameter? Depending on what behavior you want, there may be different ways to accomplish it.

Comment: @mkobit would like to pass with a REST command that comes from a webhook in another system

Comment: You could (possibly, I don't fully understand your desired workflow yet) use the [`input` step to get user input](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/), calculate a time, and use the [`sleep` step to wait until that time to resume](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-sleep-code-sleep).